# how to use grep to search for text containing square brackets("[ ]") in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am trying to searching a file to for text containing "[]" brackets. For example,

```
list[1];
i[ab1];
```

I tried `grep -i \[[a-z||1-9]*\] myfile`. But it doesn't work. These square brackets are special characters. I don't know how to escaping there special meaning. Can anybody give any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe add quotes around your regex?

Answer (score 6):

`[` is a special character in a regular expression, since it is used to denote a range (just as you use it for in the subexpression `[a-z||1-9]`). You need to *escape* it so that grep will interpret it as a literal `[` character; you do this by preceeding it with a backslash.

However, backslashes are also escape characters in the shell. To pass a single backslash to grep, you need to double it on the shell command line! You also need to escape the `|` characters and really should escape the `*` character, since these are also special to the shell:

```
grep -i \\[[a-z\|\|1-9]\*\\] myfile
```

It gets a bit easier if you just enclose the whole string in double quote marks:

```
grep -i "\\[[a-z||1-9]*\\]" myfile
```

Note that you still need to double the backslashes, as they can escape characters in a quoted string too. Even better would be to use a string enclosed with *single* quotes, in which backslashes don't act as an escape:

```
grep -i '\[[a-z||1-9]*\]' myfile
```

Comment: @ davmac: I didn't quite understand why to escape the square bracket we need double backslash while to escape |  only one backslash is needed since both of them are special characters? can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @Jerry, the `[` character is special to grep and so needs to be "escaped" so that it interprets it just as an actual `[` character. You do this by preceeding it with a backslash '\'. However, the backslash character is special to the shell, so it needs to be escaped, which you do (again) by preceeding it with a backslash. Hence you end up with two backslashes - one to escape in the shell; the shell then passes a single backslash to grep, which sees it as escaping the '[' character. '|' is not special to grep, only to the shell, so needs only be escaped once.

Comment: Thanks. davmac. Your answer is thorough.

Answer (score 1):

You are not escaping enough. The shell interprets and peels off the backslashes before `grep` sees them.

A good general guidance is to always put your regular expressions in single quotes.

```
grep -i '\[[a-z1-9]*\]' myfile
```

The `||` seemed like a misunderstanding so I took it out. Between square brackets you simply put one of each character which is allowed in the match.

The square brackets have a similar meaning in the shell, which is why the first backslash only escapes them from the shell, not from `grep`.  `ls [*]` will find files named literally with a single asterisk, not all files, or all files whose name is in square brackets.  (Using `ls` here as an example with the caveat that you usually do not want to use `ls` in scripts; and just `ls` will list all files; and `echo [*]` will also list all files matching the wildcard expression -- though in Bash out of the box, if you get no matches, the wildcard will not be expanded, and so the error message might confusingly suggest that the wildcard didn't work.)

Not quoting arguments can be very dangerous, because the outcome of an unexpected wildcard expansion will depend on which files exist in the current directory.  Behold:

```
vnix$ echo '|' >myfile

vnix$ grep -i \[[a-z||1-9]*\] myfile
grep: brackets ([ ]) not balanced
-bash: 1-9]*]: command not found

vnix$ grep -i \[[a-z\|\|1-9]*\] myfile

vnix$ # Right.  No matches.  But watch:

vnix$ touch '[|]'

vnix$ grep -i \[[a-z\|\|1-9]*\] myfile
|

vnix$ # !?! WTF?

vnix$ printf '<%s>\n' grep -i \[[a-z\|\|1-9]*\] myfile
<grep>
<-i>
<[|]>
<myfile>
```

So -- the shell expanded the unquoted regular expression as a wildcard *when there was a matching file* and you ended up grepping for something else than what you thought you were.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` are special not just in grep, but also in the shell. Your escapes just affect the shell, and they're stripped before passing to `grep`. You can add another layer of escaping with quotes:

```
$ cat myfile
list[1];
i[ab1];
othertext

$ grep -i '\[[a-z||1-9]*\]' myfile
list[1];
i[ab1];
```

Also note that your `||` match literal pipes.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried grep -i '['"[a-z||1-9]*"']' myfile. It also works.

Comment: @Jerry It does not do what you describe. For example, it matches `]` on a line by itself.