# Filter multiple words in log file using terminal

Tags: terminal, grep

I have file with lots of lines.

```
12.26.20 11 record[71] dataset[12] message[17] end[19]
12.26.20 11 record[72] dataset[12] message[20] end[21]
12.26.20 11 record[73] dataset[0] message[22] end[30]
12.26.20 11 record[74] dataset[12] message[31] end[33]
```

I need to get something like that:

```
11 record 12 17-19
11 record 12 20-21
11 record 12 31-33
```

How can i do it in terminal?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Please explain why the desired output has only three lines.

Comment: I need only lines that have "dataset[12]"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use grep to search for text containing square brackets("\[ \]") in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423473/how-to-use-grep-to-search-for-text-containing-square-brackets-in-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Awk is a good tool for this:

```
awk -F[\]\[" "] '$7 == 12 { print $2" "$3" "$7" "$10"-"$13 }' file
```

Split the lines in the file using a space, [ and ] and then print the relevant delimited fields in the format required when the 7th field is equal to 12.